# Check if URL is an image, then save it

Tags: php, curl

How would I, preferably using CURL, check if a given URL is an image, and then save the image to the server?

For example, the following link is a link to an image:

```
http://i.imgur.com/dHxqKK5.jpg
```

How would I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Either make a HEAD request, optionally followed by GET ... or download it and then check the headers and discard the download if it's not an image.

Answer (score 0):

use [get_header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) PHP function to request URL then check return array of index Content-Type